# IE too slow to add checkboxes values correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

It seems that in IE if you really quickly check/uncheck a checkbox it doesn't catch up with the last function being called.

I have this bit of code that runs perfectly fine on Chrome but in IE it just loses the actual value.

`vm.total` should increase or decrease by 1 when clicked on it. Chrome on the left, IE on the right (don't mind the minuses, I've done it other way round on the screenshots):

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to stop that or improve how fast IE reacts?

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.total = 0;
  vm.isSelected = false;
  
  vm.addSubtractOne = function() {
    if(vm.isSelected) {
      vm.total += 1;
    } else {
      vm.total -= 1;
    }
    console.log(vm.total);
  }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <form>
          <input type="checkbox" name="alertsFilter" id="alertsFilter" ng-value="1" ng-model="vm.isSelected" ng-click="vm.addSubtractOne()">
          <label for="alertsFilter">+1</label>
          <p ng-bind="vm.total"></p>
   </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```